# Using prototype and dealing with execution order

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to get a really solid grasp of JavaScript and I'm stumbling across a big issue for me. I'm used to working in C languages and one of the barriers I'm finding is dealing with the prototype functionality of JavaScript and when functions are declared, as it is concerned with the order of execution.

For instance, take the following code:

```
var construct = new Constructor(); //I can do this even if its above the declaration of the object.

construct.MyPrivilagedFunction(); //Can do this here too, even though it's above the function declaration.

construct.MyPublicFunction(); //Can't do this because it is above the function declaration.

function Constructor() {

    //Private member
    var m_Ding = "Ding!";

    //Accessible publicly and has access to private member.
    this.MyPrivilagedFunction = function() {
    console.log(m_Ding);
    }
}
Constuctor.prototype.MyPublicFunction = function() {
    //Doesn't have access to private members. This doesn't work.
    console.log(m_Ding);
}
```

I understand that prototyping provides better performance because then a copy of the function is not stored on every instance of your object and instead every instance is referring to the same function (and I guess each new instance could be considered a whole new object type?). However, prototyping does not allow me to use a function before it is defined. Furthermore, a prototyped function doesn't have access to a private member of the object.

This is only really a problem because I am working on a project where two objects will need to use each other's functions. If I place one object earlier in the code, it won't have access to the second object because prototyped functions adhere to the order of execution (top to bottom).

Side Note: I'm also aware that my object should probably be an object literal ( like object={property:value}), but I'm still trying to get a solid grasp on scope and prototyping to attempt to deal with that for now.

Comment: what's the question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

if i get you well, the root of your problem is  "two objects will need to use 
each other's functions."

But in fact Javascript is not a typed language : define TypeA, define TypeB, 
after that you can use instances : typeA and typeB objects with no issue.

```
var Speaker = function(name) {
    this.name = name ;
};

Speaker.prototype.sayHi = function(aMate) {
   amate.listenTo(this, ' Hi ' + this.mate.name ); // no type checking performed here
                                                   // so no issue even if Listener 
                                                   // is not defined yet
};

var Listener = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.knownMate = [];
};

Listener.prototype.listenTo = function (mate, words) {
    this.knownMate.push(mate);
};

var aSpeaker  = new Speaker('Joe');
var aListener = new Listener('Bobby');

aSpeaker.sayHi(aListener);
```

And by the way, you do not have private members in Javascript, only closures.
So yes, any function defined outside the scope of the 'private' member will
not be able to read/write to it.
Be advised also that, if performance is an issue, closures are slower on the
less performant js engine. 
A not-so-bad solution to have 'pseudo-private' members is to define those members
as not enumerable with Object.defineProperty()
(watch here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty  )

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution is the one you write. There are only two exceptions from the rule "everything below is irrelevant": variable and function declarations are hoisted, i.e. you can use (assign to, call) them above. And beware of the [difference between function declarations and function expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572).

> `var construct = new Constructor() //I can do this even if its above the declaration of the object.`

Declaration of the constructor function you want to say.

> `construct.MyPrivilagedFunction(); //Can do this here too, even though it's above the function declaration.`

There is no function declaration in here. The privileged method was created (with an assignment of a function expression to a property) during the execution of the constructor function (see above).

> `construct.MyPublicFunction(); //Can't do this because it is above the function declaration.`

Again, it is no function declaration but an assignment of a function expression. And it didn't happen yet, because it is below.

> This is only really a problem because I am working on a project where two objects will need to use each other's functions. If I place one object earlier in the code, it won't have access to the second object because prototyped functions adhere to the order of execution (top to bottom).

You usually don't need access to anything before you call anything. "Declare" everything at first (constructor, prototype properties), then instantiate.