# Constructor not working?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

New to JS and i'm having trouble figuring out how to run the constructor of newly created objects.

```
var player = new Player();
alert(player.getPosition()); // [ undefined, undefined ]

function Player()
{
    //afaik the x & y vars should fill when creating a new Player object.
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1), 
        y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1);
}

Player.prototype.getPosition = function()
{
    return [this.x, this.y];
}
```

Comment: Your code does throw an `Unhandled Error: 'player.getPosition' is not a function`. See [Using prototype and dealing with execution order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15184446/1048572)

Comment: Local variables have nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: @SLaks: I see now, but it's an issue that the *posted* code definitely has :-)

Comment: For the other issue, see [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not assigning `x` and `y` to the instance of `Player`. Try this instead

```
function Player()
{
    this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1);
    this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  function Player()
  {
//afaik the x & y vars should fill when creating a new Player object.
 this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1); 
 this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1);
   }
```